# Getting a select multiple element to have a drop down button

Tags: html

I notice that if you add multiple to a select element then all of  the options are shown, while without `multiple` the element has a drop down button. I would like to have the drop down button and then be able to select multiple items from the drop down list.  Is this possible?

There's a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6KWr/3/

```
<select id="delete_dropdown" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option  value="2">2</option>
    <option  value="3">3</option>
    <option  value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option  value="6">6</option>
    <option  value="7">7</option>
    <option  value="8">8</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: Multiple selection works with listboxes. Not sure if it works with dropdown menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the dropdown cannot allow multiple selection. For doing so you have to use some other plugin which will allow multiple selection while looking like a dropdown.

There are some plugins which you can find here

1. https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/
2. http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget
3. http://blogs.prakashinfotech.com/multi-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-plug-in-chosen.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in HTML.  If you're interest in jQuery plugins then check

### Multiple Select in [Chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

or

### Multi-Value Select Boxes in [Select2.js](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)